# How do i chain custom function after a delay?

Tags: jquery, function

How do i chain custom function after a delay has been set

here's what i mean: http://jsbin.com/uluyim

```
$(function(){

  $('.container').hide();

  $('.container').delay(2000).fadeIn().$(document).callMe();   

function callMe () {
  alert ("It works!");

} 

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change line below

```
$('.container').delay(2000).fadeIn().$(document).callMe();
```

to

```
$('.container').delay(2000).fadeIn(callMe)
```

Comment: @arunes Thank You!..

Is it possible to call a function that was on a separate js file? eg. script.js [$('.container').delay(2000).fadeIn(callMe)] & external.js[functions callMe() {...}]

Comment: Yes it is possible too. Of course if you add js file which have function `callMe` to document with `<script>` tag. Btw if answer helped you, mark as a answered ;)

Answer (score 6):

In your case, you can use arunes's solution, using the callback from the animation. However, if you need to add a delay between the animation and the callback that gets executed, you can do that too, as in:

```
$('.container').fadeIn(function () {
  $(this).delay(2000).queue(function () {
    alert('Custom function executed two seconds after fadeIn()!');
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the jQuery animation methods have completion callbacks that allow you to run code after animation is done

```
$('.container').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(callMe) ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $('.container').hide();

  $('.container').delay(2000).fadeIn(callMe);   

});

function callMe () {
  alert ("It works!");
```